# Configure Leiningen for integration testing

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I wonder how I can do the following things in Leiningen (if this is the idiomatic way to solve it):

1. I'd like to move my integration tests from the unit tests located in
   the `test` folder to another folder, say `integration-test`. I suppose that this means that I have to configure Leiningen to add `integration-test` to the "test classpath".
2. I'd like to create a new task that executes only the integration tests
3. I'd like to hook in the new integration test task to the install task

I'm using Midje as test library (if that matters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation I've managed to find a solution that I'm pleased with. First off all Midje provide [filters](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Using-metadata-to-filter-facts) that allows you to tag a fact with a keyword. You can then run tagged facts like this:

```
lein midje :filters it
```

This will run facts that are tagged with the :it keyword.

Next we can add a new folder for our integration tests in Leiningen:

```
:test-paths ["test" "itest"]
```

The `itest` folder will now be picked up by Leiningen and added to classpath.

If we find it hard to remember to write `lein midje :filters it` everytime we run our integration tests we can add an alias to Leiningen:

```
:aliases {"itest" ["midje" ":filters" "it"]}
```

I've also written a [blog](http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/09/integration-testing-setup-with-midje-and-leiningen/) about this with some more details if anyone is interested.